# google app engine - auto increment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google App Engine,
I have this entites User class - 
user_id - integer
user_name - string 
password - string

I want to do auto increment for the user_id,How I can do this?

Comment: Be aware that app engine does not guarantee that the ids it generates will be contiguous - you might end up with ids 1, 2, and 4 for example, with id 3 never being used.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to declare user_id, GAE will create a unique key id every time you insert a new row.

```
class User(db.Model):
user_name = db.StringProperty()
password = db.StringProperty()
```

and to store a new user you will do:

```
user = User()
user.user_name = "Username"
user.password = "Password"
user.put()
```

to retrieve it:

```
user = User.get_by_id(<id of the user>)
```

to retrieve all the ids:

```
query = datamodel.User().all()
for result in query:
    print result.key().id()
```

See [The Model Class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 3):

Every entity in the AppEngine already has a unique key and id (see the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Introduction)):

```
user().key().id()
```

You would be better off using that instead.

To do the converse, use [`User.get_by_id(id)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id).